# How to measure "linear dependence" of more than two vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking for a way to measure the linear dependence of more than two vectors.  For two vectors, we know that one way to measure its linear dependence is the angle between the two. If the vectors can be put in a square matrix, maybe we can use the determinant to do so? Is there any way other than this?  And if how do we do it with more than two vectors?

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: The angle seems like too much work for just two vectors - if two vectors are linearly dependent, then one is a multiple of the other. If you have $n$ vectors of length $n$, then they can be put as the columns of a square matrix and the determinant is zero if and only if there is a dependency. (Of course if you have more than $n$ vectors of length $n$, they're automatically dependent).

Comment: Set their linear combination equal to zero and solve for the coefficients. The vectors are independant iff those coefficients are all zero. Now, if you have to do this with dozens or hundreds of vectors, I suspect that's far from computationally efficient...

Comment: If you have $N$ vectors $v_1,\ldots, v_N$ in $\mathbb R^N$, you could look at the condition number of the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & \cdots & v_N \end{bmatrix}$.  The condition number of $A$ measures how "close to singular" $A$ is.  It's equal to the ratio of the maximum and minimum singular values of $A$.

Answer (score 8):

The singular value decomposition http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition is a good choice. Form a matrix whose columns are the vectors, and look at the smallest singular value.

Comment: Thank you. That really helpful.

Comment: Thank you. That really helpful.

My question is more about how to detect $d$ linearly independent vectors in a set of $n$ vectors.  And there is noise in these $n$ vectors. What I was thinking is to pick any group of $d$ vectors and figure out which group is the least linear dependence.  That is why I need a way to measure the linear dependence of $d$ vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Besides singular decomposition even the simple Gaussian elimination will do: construct a matrix from your vectors and do gaussian elimination to triangular shape. A measure for "degree of independence" can then simply be chosen as the number of non-zero diagonal elements (or some function of it). It is also called "rank (of a matrix)".

Answer (score 0):

[Wedge Product Formula For Sine. Analogous Formula Generalizing Cosine to Higher Dimensions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1225933/wedge-product-formula-for-sine-analogous-formula-generalizing-cosine-to-higher/1226203?noredirect=1#comment2494210_1226203) SUPER late, but checkout my post here. Look at the ratio of the determinant over the maximum possible determinant vs the lengths. This is an effective measure of linear **IN**dependence. take the arcsin to get the generalized "angle".

Comment: It would be an improvement to provide a more substantial summary of what a Reader would find if they follow your link.  It seems you are in essence just referencing a previous Math.SE Answer, which might better be pointed out with a Comment unless you have something to add in relation to the current Question.