# Generalized cosine for $n$ vectors in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

In the vector space $\mathbb R^2$, writing $\phi(v,w)$ for the angle from vector $v$ to vector $w$, we have
$$
\sin\phi(v,w)=\frac{\det(v,w)}{|v||w|}.
$$
More generally, in $\mathbb R^n$, we could define
$$
S(v_0,\dots,v_{n-1})=\frac{\det(v_0,\dots,v_{n-1})}{|v_0|\cdots|v_{n-1}|},
$$
and consider $S$ as generalizing $\sin\circ\phi$ to $n$-dimension. $S$ has the following property:
(i) when some vectors are along the same direction, then the parallelepiped formed by the normalized vectors has no volume, and $S(v_0,\dots,v_{n-1})=0$. (ii) when they are orthogonal to each other, then $S$ achieves the maximum value 1. $S$ has other properties, such as being alternating.

Is there an analogue for cosine? If we call it $C$, then for $\mathbb R^2$, we should have
$$
C(v,w)=\frac{\langle v,w\rangle}{|v||w|}.
$$
$C$ probably should have the following property: (i) when all vectors are along the same direction, it achieves the maximum value 1. (ii) when some vectors are orthogonal to each other, $C(v_0,\dots,v_{n-1})=0$.

The question has been asked before, but has got no answer so far. An alternative formulation might also have some value.

SSD (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/228795/ssd), Wedge Product Formula For Sine. Analogous Formula Generalizing Cosine to Higher Dimensions?, URL (version: 2015-04-09): [Wedge Product Formula For Sine. Analogous Formula Generalizing Cosine to Higher Dimensions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1225933)

Comment: This question might be better on mathoverflow.se.